# Installing new classes into TeXstudio

Tags: installing, document-classes, exam

I'm about to be a first-year graduate student and was asked to write a first draft of a calculus one midterm.

I have always used TeXstudio for homework and research papers I have written and they only required the document class "article", but when I tried to write something in the document class "exam" I got the error  "File `exam.cls' not found". I downloaded the exam.cls file, but I can't figure out how to install the file so that I can use the exam document class. I've read a few things online, but they didn't make much sense to me. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Have you installed a TeX distribution? If no, I don't know why you can use `article`. If yes, you must be able to use `exam`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but I downloaded and installed TeXstudio, and I don't get any errors like "File `exam.cls' not found" when I use the document class article. For example, the compiler has no problems reading the line \documentclass{article}, but won't read anything after \documentclass{exam}

Comment: `article` and `exam` are all automatically installed when you install LaTeX. Therefore if you can't compile with `exam`, you can't compile with `article` either.

Comment: What other errors do you think might be preventing me from using this document class?    '\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
 This is a test

\end{document}'                                                                                             
doesn't compile,while                                                           \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
 This is a test

\end{document} compiles perfectly

Comment: We need to read the log file, or at least the error messages. How did you install MikTeX (or TeXlive)?

Comment: You said *exam.cls*. So, simply put it on the same folder as `tex` file. This should work locally.

Comment: @sigur I'm not sure, I just followed the prompted instructions when I installed the TeXstudio application I'll give your suggestion a try right now

Comment: Are you using Linux? Did you install TeXstudio from repository?

Comment: I'm on a macbook, and I don't know what it means to install from repository. I tried moving the downloaded "exam.cls" folder into the resources folded in TeXstudio, but that didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to install classes by hand. Use the package manager from TeX to install it.

Comment: What is that? I don't see that in any of the available commands while running texstudio.

Comment: Search for tex in your computer, not related to TeXstudio, which is only an editor.

Comment: Should that be a folder, or an application? When I search my Mac for "tex" I get 149 files with the name "Tex", and they all have different content. Most of them seem to have either .js files in them, or .woff files in them if that means anything to you.

Comment: Do you on occasion use sudo tlmgr update ? if so then your underlying tex is TexLive and tlmgr is the manager for loading packages

Comment: I have a single folder called "texlive" but in that folder there is nothing that I can see that would allow me to install or load a package. The only thing I find under "tlmgr" is something called "spkg-install"

Comment: I think I need to talk to someone in person about this. I'll see if my advisor has something to say about this on Monday. Thanks for your help, and sorry to take up your time.

Comment: Good luck what we are trying NOT to do is give wrong advice for your specific case but without knowing which TeX Live Utility you have for example in /Applications/TeX we are unsure how to proceed for you to load exam package